# How do I export every commit in git into its own numbered archive?

Tags: git

I started using git for versioning for binary files (.ai & .indd). I was wondering how I would go about exporting every commit of one of those files (or the whole repo) so that afterwards I would have an image sequence which I could use to make a video like this one[moxie doxy](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zkbijkA47Ag&feature=youtu.be&hd=1) which was made from files being saved as typeface(n), typeface(n++)….

so what I guess I am trying to achieve is something like this:

Git archive -o export iterateOverAllCommits EXPORTS_TO (first commit)archive0001.zip, (second commit)archive0002.zip…

After that it's no trouble to expand/prepare files for video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By combining `git archive` and `git rev-list` with a little bash, you can do so.

```
COUNT=0
for commit in `git rev-list --reverse HEAD`; do
  git archive $commit --format=zip -o archive$COUNT.zip
  COUNT=$((COUNT + 1))
done
```

`git rev-list --reverse HEAD` prints out commit hashes starting with the first commit and ending with HEAD.

`git archive $commit --format=zip -o archive$COUNT.zip` creates a zip archive of the commit specified by the commit hash from `rev-list`.

Both `rev-list` and `archive` have a lot of options, which could help you further refine the archives to contain the information you need only.

[Using printf](http://jonathanwagner.net/2007/04/zero-padding-in-bash/) you could easily modify the above to zero-pad the count.